# error on insertion variable data in oracle database using php code

Tags: php, oracle

i am trying to run this php code to insert values in oracle database but error showing when run it. my code is:

```
<?php 
$c = oci_connect('system', 'passward', 'dbname');
$sql = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(EMP_ID,JOB_ID) VALUES (:emp_id, ".'{$nw}'.")";
$compiled = oci_parse($c, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':emp_id', $eid);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, '.$nw.', $nw);
oci_execute($compiled);
?>
```

and i get the folloing errors

> Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\add_emp.php on line 16
>
> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00911: invalid character in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\add_emp.php on line 17

Ι know the problem is where Ι write `$nw`, but just don't know the right syntax or way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You doing it incorrectly,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(EMP_ID,JOB_ID) VALUES (:emp_id, :nw)";
$compiled = oci_parse($c, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':emp_id', $eid);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':nw', $nw);
```

Comment: Thank you very mush Rikesh,,, i did it and it worked.

Comment: Glad to help you kindly accept it if it helps you in solving your problem.

Comment: i did it, tick marj is now green, is this what you was trying to convey??

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(EMP_ID,JOB_ID) VALUES (:emp_id, :nw)";
```

the problem in your query is that you're closing the " then concatenating {$nw} exactly this string as you've put it between single quotes, php understands that it shouldn't replace this by a variable it is just a string. so your query is arriving to oracle like this:

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMP_ID,JOB_ID) VALUES (whatever_int_in_eid, {$nw});